# String delimiter to read table data mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

instead of using String delimiter, is there any other way to do on line 7?

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM user";
$res = mysqli_query($conn, $q) or die(mysql_error());
$userList = "";
while($user = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
    $userList .= $user['userList'].";;";
}
echo $userList;
```

Comment: what do you mean "other way to do"?  what do you want to do with it?

Comment: @bart2puck why mysql return not the value but the ;; together?

Comment: so your results are ;;;;;;;;?  if so, then the query is not finding any results.

Comment: @bart2puck I got what I want, but why it come along with ;; ?

Answer (score 0):

```
 $userList .= $user['userList'].";;";
```

means  the variable named userList will be appended with the result from the query.  after each result you are appending ";;" because of the period.

if you dont want to append the ;; do the following:

```
 $q = "SELECT * FROM user";
 $res = mysqli_query($conn, $q) or die(mysql_error());
 $userList = "";
 while($user = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
      $userList .= $user['userList'];
 }
  echo $userList;
```